# Getting Wikipedia Anchor Text

Tags: wikipedia

I am trying to find a way to obtain the anchor text of all of the incoming links to a wikipedia page (from other pages within wikipedia).  I've read a few papers that that have done experiments with this information (eg. http://web2py.iiit.ac.in/research_centres/publications/download/inproceedings.pdf.809e1550d80bca59.4d756c7469446f635f53756d6d6172697a6174696f6e5f46696e616c2e706466.pdf)
but they don't seem to explain how they obtain this information.  There is one resource that I am aware of called [YAGO](https://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/departments/databases-and-information-systems/research/yago-naga/yago/) that provides the wikipedia pages that link to the page in question but it does not seem to provide the anchor text.  Can anyone suggest a way of obtaining this information?

Comment: Probably they have simply downloaded the dump and parsed the files to extract the links.

Comment: You can (and in this case **should**) always ask the authors. Their contact information is in the paper. Maybe they'll even just send you their data!

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the html texts of wikipedia pages.

Such anchor texts are like [link|anchor text] in [piped link format](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Piped_link), which you need to find by implementing [parser](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Parsing_wikitext) yourself.

You can find more detailed information in the stackoverflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27178468/read-wikipedia-piped-links)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is:

- Download Wikipedia dump file from https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/. Select `latest` and then select [enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2)
- Clean Wikipedia dump file with https://github.com/attardi/wikiextractor. Use flag `l, --links` to preserve the links

Now you have clean Wikipedia plain text which contains anchor-text. With any programming language, you can parse these files and extract anchor-texts.