# Read Wikipedia piped links

Tags: java, wikipedia

I'm using java and I want to read piped links from Wikipedia that has a specific surface form. Fir example in this form [America|US] the surface form is "US" and the internal link is "America".

The straightforward solution is to read the xml dump of Wikipedia and find the strings that matches the regular expression for a piped link. However I am afraid that I wouldn't cover all the possible regular expressions of a piped link. I searched and I couldn't find any library that specifically give me the piped links.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you looking for external links (`[http://stackoverflow.com StackOverflow]`) too, or just internal links (`[[America|US]]`)?

Comment: Also, are you going to fetch the links for a specific set of pages, or are you looking for all links?

Comment: all the internal links, no specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**edit**

Now that I understand the question: I don't think there is a way to get all internal links with their printout value. This is simply not stored in the [database](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Database_layout) (only [links](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pagelinks_table) are), because the actual output is only created when the page is rendered.

You would have to [parse the pages](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Parsing_wikitext) yourself to be sure to get all links. Of course, if you can accept getting only the subset of links available in the wikitext of each page, parsing the xml dump as you suggests would work. Note that one single regex will most likely not distinguish between piped internal links, and [piped interwiki links](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Piped_link). Also beware of image links, that use pipes for variable separation (e.g. `[[Image:MyImage.jpeg|thumb|left|A caption!]]`).

Here is the regex used by the [MediaWiki parser](https://git.wikimedia.org/blob/mediawiki%2Fcore.git/d2674373c55681b5c4f24c7183b34030487403c2/includes%2Fparser%2FParser.php):

```
$tc = Title::legalChars() . '#%';
# Match a link having the form [[namespace:link|alternate]]trail
$e1 = "/^([{$tc}]+)(?:\\|(.+?))?]](.*)\$/sD";
# Match cases where there is no "]]", which might still be images
$e1_img = "/^([{$tc}]+)\\|(.*)\$/sD";
```

However, this codes is applied after a lot of preprocessing has happened.

**Old answer**

Using a xml dump will not give you all links, as many links are produced by [templates](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Templates), or in some cases even [parser functions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ParserFunctions). A simpler way would be to use the [API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page):

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Stack_Overflow&prop=links&redirects
```

I am assuming English Wikipedia here, but it will work anywhere, just substitute `en.` in the url for your language code. The `redirects` directive will, quite obviously, make sure to follow redirects. In the same way, use `prop=extlinks` to get external links:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Stack_Overflow&prop=extlinks&redirects
```

You can grab links for multiple pages at once, either by separating their name with a pipe character, like this: `Stack_Overflow|Chicago`, or by using a generator, e.g. [`allpages`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Allpages) (to run the query against every single page in the wiki), like this:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=allpages&prop=links
```

The number of results returned by the `allpages` generator can be raise by setting the `gaplimit` parameter, e.g. `&gaplimit=50` to get [all external links for the first 50 pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=allpages&gaplimit=50&prop=links). If you request [bot status](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bots) at the Wikipedia edition you are looking at, you can get as high as 5000 results per request, otherwise the maximum is 500 for most (probably all) Wikipedias.

Comment: Your way doesn't give what I want. For example in page : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Sumner we have this sentence with this format: "In 1834, Sumner was admitted to the [[bar (law)|bar]] at the age of twenty-three, and entered private practice in Boston." So if I run your query for word "bar", it should give me "bar_(law)" as one of the answers, which it doesn't. This is what I want: I want to say go find all the internal links that the word the user see is "bar", however it is linking to that internal link with a different title from which is shown.

Comment: These links are some of the disambiguation pages for page "bar", not all of them.

Comment: Ok, so you are looking for a way to extract all piped internal links, *and* their printed out version?

Comment: yes, exactly! :) that's why I thought I have to read all the wikipedia xml and extract them into a database. I couldn't find a sparql query for that.